# How to do clear focus for Multiple EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my application i have 3 `EditText` i have issue with `focus`, I want to clear the focus of `EditText` which has the focus when user clicks on the submit button i used `edittext.clearFocus()` this will work fine if i am having single `EditText` in the layout, how can clear the focus for multiple `EditText` please help

Comment: Does all three EditText having focus on same time?? Interesting, how did you did it?

Comment: no how can that possible, my issue is when i have multiple `edittext` `edittext.clearFocus()` is not working

Comment: Add code which is not working..

Comment: the Most Amazing thing you are having focus all three fields simultaneously... Amazing

Comment: @UsmanKurd dude first read my question completely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On submit button click i tried this as [Roshan Jha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/647014/roshan-jha) suggested and it works great

```
yourEditText.setFocusable(false); 
yourEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true); 

yourEditText1.setFocusable(false); 
yourEditText1.setFocusableInTouchMode(true); 

yourEditText2.setFocusable(false); 
yourEditText2.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Just  use this when under the onclick of your button...**

when you click the submit button the focus will b lost from all the editText

```
yourEditText.setFocusable(false);
yourEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

 yourEditText1.setFocusable(false);
  yourEditText1.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

   yourEditText2.setFocusable(false);
    yourEditText2.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

**Use this in the last of your page basically after on click listener**

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
               yourEditText.setFocusable(true);
               yourEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            }

            return false;
  }
```

**UPDATED AGAIN**

```
public class ChangePassword extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
  {
TextView txtUsername, txtCancel;
Button txtSubmit, btnback;
EditText txtOldPassword, txtNewPassword, txtConfirmPassword;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.change_password);

txtOldPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_current_password);
txtOldPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        txtOldPassword.setFocusable(true);
        txtOldPassword.requestFocus();

    }

});

txtNewPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_new_password);


    txtNewPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            txtNewPassword.setFocusable(true);
            txtNewPassword.requestFocus();

        }

    });

txtConfirmPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_confirm_password);
    txtConfirmPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            txtConfirmPassword.setFocusable(true);
            txtConfirmPassword.requestFocus();

        }

    });



txtSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.txtsubmit);
btnback = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);

txtUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_login_name);
txtCancel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtcancel);

txtSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
txtCancel.setOnClickListener(this);


}

public void onClick(View view) {

      switch(view.getId())
        {


          case R.id.txtsubmit:

             txtOldPassword.setFocusable(false);
              txtNewPassword.setFocusable(false);
               txtConfirmPassword.setFocusable(false);
                break;

             case R.id.txtcancel:

                 finish();

                  break;
                      case R.id.btnBack:
                            finish();

                           break;

                     }
                }
}
```

**Your XML**

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/txt_current_password"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
android:background="@drawable/backwithborder"
android:hint="@string/hint_current_password"

android:inputType="textPassword"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textColor="#b8b8b8"
android:textSize="17sp"
android:typeface="sans" >
```

Comment: if again i want to focus then, how can i make focus true.

Comment: When user clicks on the `edittext` i want to focus again

Comment: it is working but i need to click two times on the edittext to focus again

Comment: you can add this function n times in your on create just change the value of yourEditText if u have three editText add this three times

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51224/discussion-between-wizard-and-tushar-narang)

Comment: I changed the on touch listener to onclick

Comment: Don't use XML to define onClick actions. It's error prone and very VERY slow. Set an OnclickListener via java code.

Answer (score 1):

```
getWindow().getDecorView().clearFocus();
```

just to add .. you layout should have:

```
 android:focusable="true"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
editText.setFocusable(true / false);
```